# Reasons not to commit to master

Tags: git, github, version-control

In each manual and documentation about Git you can find the following recommendation: Do not commit to master, if you need to make some changes to master, you need to create a new branch first and then merge it. So, I'm interested to know why? What benefits does this approach offer? ‌Because as far as I understand, you don't need separate branches if you want to, for example, to revert a change - you can simply do that by using previous commit's hash.

Here I found one reason - if you have many commits, it will be easier to merge branch with master then push commits one after another
http://waterstreetgm.org/git-why-you-should-never-commit-directly-to-master/

But what if your workflow is divided into many small tasks and each of these tasks fits into the one commit. So, each branch contains one commit. What are the reasons not to commit to master in this case?

Comment: At minimum, you could run automated testing on each branch to verify it won't break a stable branch. IMO, it is about stability and security.

Comment: If your branches would contain a single commit, I see nothing wrong with committing directly to master.

Comment: Did the answer help you solve the confusion?  If yes, you can mark it as answer. And it will also benefit others who have similar questions.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Those who said 'never' or 'always' (like in the accepted answer!?!) are often (always!?!  ) wrong...

⚠ **Like you will discover once you understand git, there are often multiple ways to do the same things and your choices will mostly be team choices.**

There is absolutely no rule that prevents to commit on `master`. There are advantages and disadvantages to the 2 ways of doing.

For example, the post you linked is more a problem that the writer didn't master git enough than something else...

In less than 5 minutes, he could have created its new branch and reset its local `master` to the remote ref and pushed one commit on `master` branch.

Here is a list that is not exhaustive...

Using **feature branches** (also known as `GitHub flow`) :

Pros:

- you could see clearly where the features are introduced in the software (when the branch is merged)
- that makes code review easier (just before merging or during all the development if you made a pull request early, which is a good practice)
- easily reverted if needed (just have to revert the merge commit)
- easily do proof of concept (but hard to reintroduce in master)
- only working workflow when doing remote or opensource development that require code review or CI results before merging commits (but should not necessarily be used in companies because it is successful in open source world)

Cons:

- git history could be difficult to read (for that, a `rebase` just before the `merge` could make the history easier to read)
- devs could easily enter in a tunnel effect without synchronization with the master (preferably made with a rebase instead of sync merges) and end up with a merge hell in the end

Using **"trunk Based development"** (and `feature toggles`. Real good development practice that you should have a look) :

Pros:

- real continuous integration (with all its benefits like discovering bugs sooner)
- prevent merge hells
- less cumbersome and easier to master in git
- perfectly fine when you are the only developer
- a prerequisite when you want to do continuous deployment / delivery (each commit is a small step that minimize the risk of introducing a big bug hard to find the cause in the lot of lines of code changed)
- A good Infoq article telling that it's needed to continuous delivery (a DevOps practice): [Trunk Based Development as a Cornerstone for Continuous Delivery](https://www.infoq.com/news/2018/04/trunk-based-development/)
- Someone made a very   exhaustive website on the subject: https://trunkbaseddevelopment.com/

Cons:

- not a clear moment when a feature is introduced (should have a look to the feature toggle enabled)
- require to have good development practices like writing unit tests  (but could also be seen as a pros)
- need (sometimes) mastering branching by abstraction ([a good explanation by Martin Fowler](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/BranchByAbstraction.html) ). That reduces risks but take more time.

Choose the one that suits your team and stick to it most of the time and apply the other when you think it makes more sense and solve a new problem you encountered...

A very good, long and complete article on the subject by Martin Fowler: https://martinfowler.com/articles/branching-patterns.html (§ `Comparing Feature Branching and Continuous Integration`. But you will have to read nearly all to get it well...)

Comment: There’s nothing good about trunk-based development in Git as far as I can tell. Feature toggles increase the complexity of code and make refactoring harder, as well as creating dead code. We all did trunk-based development on SVN, but that’s because branching and merging was hard. You don’t need trunk-based development to get real continuous integration in Git; you just need devs to be able to merge master into the feature branches frequently (which I always do when working on a feature branch). Trunk-based development cripples Git’s power for no real advantage.

Comment: (I do feature branches even on my solo projects. I find it useful to play with various features without needing to complete each one.)

Comment: @Marnen I'm not sure the one that promotes Continuous Integration and devops practices will agree with you...

Comment: I don’t understand your comment well enough to respond to it. Your phrasing is unclear. Try again?

Comment: @MarnenLaibow-Koser I have updated my answer with 2 links on articles that will explain it better than me in 500 characters long comment.

Comment: I’ve read Fowler’s articles on the subject, as well as some from his colleagues at ThoughtWorks. I respect Fowler greatly, but he got this one mostly wrong.

Comment: Meanwhile, your other link to trunkbaseddevelopment.com *recommends* short-lived feature branches—exactly what I am advocating.

Comment: @MarnenLaibow-Koser on this subject, that was the 3rd link from infoq the more interesting. But the main problem is not that you can't do short term branches. Because obviously, you can. That's just that the more a branch contains commits, the more you have uncertainty on what you will merge and that's what you want to avoid when you do continuous deployment.

Comment: With trunk base you could do A/B testing, dark deployment, deployment of not finished features to test part of a code... With feature branches, it a all or nothing and praying when deploying...

Comment: That is entirely backwards. With feature branches, you can do thorough testing *before* the branches are merged into master and deployed (and you can even merge master into the feature branch to test the integration if you want). It’s with trunk-based development that you need to pray and hope that you didn’t screw anything up. Maybe you just don’t know how to use branches effectively?

Comment: Also, you could do dark launching and A/B testing with feature branches too. Anything doable with trunk-based development is doable with feature branches, because the code doesn’t care. But feature branches allow for better testing and more controlled integration. That’s why I believe trunk-based development is a big mistake in a VCS that allows easy merging.

Comment: @MarnenLaibow-Koser I have added a link on a Martin Fowler article that explains better than me my point of view and that 'feature branching" is not the definitive best practice you want it to be... (Even if it could be the best one for opensource projects.)

Comment: As I’ve said above, I’m aware of (at least some of) Fowler’s thoughts on this topic, and my experience, at least, has shown me that they’re pretty much incorrect.

Answer (score 14):

If you're working with multiple people you should always have separate branches and only merge with the master when the bit you're adding/changing is finished and fully tested.

If you're on your own small project there isn't as much of a distinction. If your adding functionality, tags could be used just as well to be able to come back to a given commit.

Not committing to master prevents colliding commits and having to merge each time 2 people change the same file.

Comment: Your last paragraph is a bad practice because if 2 people are working on the same file and you didn't sync often (what you call 'merge often'), the probability that one of the 2 will have to solve a big merge hell increase with time and number of commit in the branch. And so, increase a lot to introduce a bug during a merge. Bad practice and one of the worst when working in feature branches.

Comment: Well I specifically mean merging on every commit, is there a best practice for how often to sync? I would think it is very project dependent.

Comment: The best (and theoretical) practice is 'as soon as you can' to do real continuous integration (that's the aim of 'trunk base development'). But indeed each project has to find its tradeoff because that could be a little costly...

Comment: @Philippe Each person working on a branch should merge master into that branch frequently so that they can deal with merging without cluttering master with it.

Comment: @MarnenLaibow-Koser which leads to an horrible git history.I hope you will never have to dig into it to understand a bug...When you do feature branching, syncing with `git rebase` is often better.

Comment: @Philippe I dig into merged histories to understand bugs quite often. It’s much *easier* to understand bugs with a merged history than with a rebased one, since you know that every commit is in the state that it was originally made (and as always, `git bisect` is your friend). Rebase makes commits that represent a state of the system that’s never been tested, so it makes the history less reliable.  Personally, I think artificially linearizing your history is the horrible thing here.

Comment: @MarnenLaibow-Koser you misunderstood. I was talking to sync a feature branch with merges instead of rebase. Not to never merge. If you do feature branches, they have to be merged at the end, instead of rebased. For sync by merging, I let you imagine if you are not alone working in the feature branch...

Comment: @Philippe Everywhere I’ve worked, a feature branch only gets worked on by one developer (or pair) at a time. But even if that weren’t the case, so what? I really don’t understand this fear of merge commits that I often see.